# How do I send an embedded image in gmail

Tags: image, email, hyperlink

I want to send links like : http://www.geekinheels.com/storage/world_of_programming.jpg as emedded image. Is that possible.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this pragmatically or using gmail if using gmail look at http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/new-in-labs-inserting-images.html?

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the src attribute of the img tag inside your HTML body to "cid:XXXXX", where XXXXX is some string/identifier, e.g. "world_of_programming.jpg".

After that add your image as an attachment with Content-ID equal to "XXXXX", e.g.

`Content-ID: world_of_programming.jpg`

and you're good to go.